# Animating Bone Chains: Using the Last Bone to Drive the Movement of the Entire Chain

Tags: animation, armature, bones, bone.constraints

I would like to achieve the following: given an armature and a chain of bones connected in a parent-child relationship, when I move the last bone in the chain, I want all the other bones to move accordingly, while respecting rotation constraints on specific axes. How can I achieve this effect?

[image]

As requested in the comments, I'll attempt to better explain what I aim to achieve. The final bone should track an object moving along a plane. The robot should lower itself, grab the object, and place it aside. Currently, I am constrained to manually manipulate each axis of the robot to chase the moving object, lower the picker, and then proceed with the motion to place it beside the robot.

[image]

Comment: i don't know what you mean with "accordingly"? Can you specify this a bit more pls? And what is the difference of just adding an IK to your last two bones and what you wanna have?

Comment: As Chris says, the IK constraint allows that, or enable the Pose Options > Auto IK?

Comment: @moonboots I added some more details...

Comment: @Chris I added some more details...

Comment: again...this can an IK do...do you know what IK is and did you ever use an IK?

Comment: @Chris Thanks Chris for pointing me in the right direction, I'll try to watch some tutorials.